# firebase admin pip install after getting error

Tags: python, firebase

I have installed firebase-admin pip for python2

```
sudo pip install firebase-admin
```

and create a file and import it, it is working fine in python2

```
import firebase_admin
```

but when i use "credentials" then it generate an error

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/google.py", line 24, in <module>
    from firebase_admin import credentials
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/firebase_admin/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from firebase_admin import credentials
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/firebase_admin/credentials.py", line 21, in <module>
    from google.auth.transport import requests
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 37, in <module>
    from google.auth import exceptions
  File "/var/www/html/google.py", line 24, in <module>
    from firebase_admin import credentials
ImportError: cannot import name credentials
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use python 3.

> Few libraries are not supported on the App Engine standard python 2.7
>   runtime. They are supported on the Python 3 runtime for standard.
>   ([Reference](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/5846#issuecomment-416277921))

Below code will fix your credentials ImportError.

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import auth
from firebase_admin import credentials

# Initialize the default app
cred = credentials.Certificate('path/to/serviceAccountKey.json')
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
```

Useful link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Answer (score 1):

I can see you are using python version 2.7 which is not compatible for firebase-admin package.

As per documentation, you need to have Python version >=3.5

You can download latest version of python from here: 
[Python Latest Version Download](https://www.python.org/downloads/)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) For example adding links to those docs might be helpful.